# Python Kivy not matching object to rule

Tags: python, kivy

I'm new to Kivy, and I don't seem to understand the syntax for defining and then referencing a rule in a KV file.

For example, when I define a rule against the actual Widget class name (in this case, the ScrollView widget), the code works correctly:

In *xxx.py*:

```
class XxxApp():
    ...
    scroller = ScrollView()
```

In *xxx.kv*:

```
<ScrollView>:
    size_hint: (None, None)
    size: (400, 400)
    pos_hint: {u'left_x': .5, u'center_y': .5}
```

whereas when I invent a name (in this example, "Scroller") and try to define a rule for it, the code doesn't crash, but the running program ignores the defined rule:

In *xxx.py*:

```
class Scroller(Widget):
    pass

class XxxApp():
    ...
    scroller = Scroller()
```

In *xxx.kv*:

```
<Scroller>:
    ScrollView:
        size_hint: (None, None)
        size: (400, 400)
        pos_hint: {u'left_x': .5, u'center_y': .5}
```

Could you tell me how to get Kivy to match up "Scroller()" to the rule I defined for it, which is identical to the rule I defined for "ScrollView" in the example that worked?

UPDATE:

By the way, the following also works:

In *xxx.py*:

```
class Scroller(ScrollView):
    pass

class XxxApp():
    ...
    scroller = Scroller()
```

In *xxx.kv*:

```
<Scroller>:
    size_hint: (None, None)
    size: (400, 400)
    pos_hint: {u'left_x': .5, u'center_y': .5}
```

While this works, it's not a satisfactory solution, because it requires the Python code to specify what kind of Widget to use for Scroller. I just want to define Scroller as a subclass of Widget in the Python code, and then specify what kind of Widget to use (in this case, a ScrollView) in the KV file. That's how many of the Kivy examples I've seen are coded.

So the problem I'm having is not that Kivy is not matching up Scroller from the Python code to the KV file as I originally thought. The problem is that when I define the rule for Scroller so that it contains a ScrollView widget, and then define properties for that ScrollView widget, Kivy ignores those property definitions.

RUNNABLE EXAMPLE

*sample.py*

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class SampleLabel(Widget):
    pass


class SampleApp(App):
    def build(self):

        # To illustrate the problem, comment out one of the two following statements

        # root = Label()  # Use this statement to see the app work correctly, displaying "Sample Text"
        root = SampleLabel()  # Use this statement to see the app fail, not displaying "Sample Text"

        root.text = u'Sample Text'
        return root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    SampleApp().run()
```

*sample.kv*

```
#:kivy 1.9.0

<Label>:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: 40

<SampleLabel>:
    Label:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 40
```

Comment: Should `ScrollView:` really be in `<Scroller>` definition?

Comment: Hi, Torxed. How would Kivy know what kind of Widget to create if I don't tell it? Please tell me how to correct this definition so that it works.

Answer (score 0):

kv rules are for widget classes. Scroller is not a widget class, it doesn't inherit from anything. Perhaps you meant

```
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget  # or some other Widget class
class Scroller(Widget):
    ...
```

Also, I'd discourage creating a rule like `<ScrollView>:` for a built in widget - this will affect all ScrollViews, and could have weird effects. Instead, make a subclass and create a rule for that.

Also ...

```
class XxxApp():
    ...
    scroller = Scroller()
```

...this doesn't do anything, scroller is just a class level variable, it won't actually do anything with it.

Comment: Hi, inclement. You're right about Scroller(Widget) vs Scroller(). In my actual code with this problem, I used Scroller(Widget), and I've edited my original question to show Scroller defined that way.

Comment: Continuing: I don't want to have a rule for <ScollView> for the very reason you gave. The whole point of my question is that I have not figured out how to define a subclass. That's what I was trying to do: Make Scroller be a class that consists of a ScrollView widget.

Comment: Continuing: With respect to "this doesn't do anything", what I'm trying to do with "scroller = Scroller()", based on every example I've seen, is to create an instance of a ScrollView widget with the properties defined in the KV file for the Scroller rule. Please tell me how to define Scroller as a ScrollView widget with particular properties and then create an instance of it in the Python code. That's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: You *did* create an instance, you *didn't* do anything with it. If you want it to be your root widget, return the instance from the build method of your App class.

Comment: I was just showing the part of the code that works vs the part that doesn't work. I do return the instance from my build method. Please look at the two versions I showed that work, and compare to the one that doesn't. The only difference is that the one that doesn't work tries to define Scroller as containing a ScrollView. That's the only thing I need help with, how to specify in the KV file that Scroller contains a particular kind of Widget (in my case, a ScrollView), just as so many examples on the web do.

Comment: By the way, please note the example in the UPDATE to my question, since I do not want to specify ScrollView as the base class of Scroller in the Python code, I want to specify ScrollView as part of the definition of Scroller in the KV file.

Comment: Post a runnable example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Hi, inclement. Thanks for all your help with this. I'll add the runnable example to the original question, since I don't know how to add it to this comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try to not use u"", sometimes it leads to wierd unicode decode errors using kivy with py2. Just use "" and you'll be a lot hapier.

Your runable example has a mistake.

```
class SampleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root = SampleLabel()  

        root.text = u'Sample Text'
        return root
```

when you do:

```
    root.text = u'Sample Text'
```

you are doing it to a SampleLabel. But your SampleLabel doesnt have a text property because is an instance of Widget and not an instance of Label.
Kivy doesnt crashes because it creates the property automatically. Creates and nothing else, i mean, kivy doesnt display it like in a Label.

You can do something like this:

sample.kv

```
#:kivy 1.9.0

<SampleLabel>:
    Label:
        id: label_in_sample_label  # this will give you access to THIS label 
                                   # through python code     
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 40
```

sample.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class SampleLabel(Widget):
    pass


class SampleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root = SampleLabel() 

        # Now you can set a text to it :D    
        root.ids.label_in_sample_label.text = u'Sample Text'
        return root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    SampleApp().run()
```

This way you can define complex widgets. But if you simply want a custom label you dont need to change your kivy code. Just inherit SampleLabel from Label instead from widget:

```
class SampleLabel(Label):
    pass
```

I hope this answers your question.